open man page does not work in zsh in Sonoma: Unknown locale, assuming C No manual entry for tree
MacOs

Sonoma v 14.6.1
chip M1 Pro
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

selecting command in terminal and right click and choose open man page opens a text editor and display
Unknown locale, assuming C
No manual entry for tree

[Process completed]



If you are are specifically asking about tree, that is not included in the standard macOS installation.

No, I am asking for any command. check in screenshot it is about ls

Why're you running Terminal under Rosetta?

what means by Rosetta?

According to your question, you are running an x86 version of zsh on an M1.  To do that, you are running the shell (and the terminal) under Rosetta.  Why?

As This is default terminal shell. I have not dony any customisation/ configuration  for that
